# Find no. of occurrence of each character in a string

Tags: c#

Given a string I need to count the number of instances of each character. My code is below. I hope it is easy to understand my logic.

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Firstname = txtFname.Text;
        var lastName = txtLastName.Text;
        var FullName = Firstname + "" + lastName;

        char[] charArray = FullName.ToLower().ToCharArray();
        Dictionary<char, int> counter = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        int tempVar = 0;
        foreach (var item in charArray)
        {
            if (counter.TryGetValue(item, out tempVar))
            {
                counter[item] += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                counter.Add(item, 1);
            }
        }
        //var numberofchars = "";
        foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int> item in counter)
        {
            if (counter.Count > 0)
            {
                //Label1.Text=split(item.
            }
            Response.Write(item.Value + " " + item.Key + "<br />");  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read the [help] to understand what kind of questions you can ask here. As far this one- it's not even clear what you are asking for. Since you provide C# code, it looks like you''re asking other people to write the Java/C code for you. "Write my code for me" questions are not suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: Please don't shotgun a bunch of tags in order to attempt to reach a wider audience.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
string FullName = Firstname + "" + lastName;
var result = FullName.GroupBy(c => c)
                     .Where(c => c.Count() > 1)
                     .Select(c => new 
                                    { 
                                        charName = c.Key, 
                                        charCount = c.Count()
                                    });
```